# Get enabled extensions from org.gnome.shell schema in GJS

Tags: gnome, gjs

I am trying to obtain the value stored in the org.gnome.shell schema with the enabled extensions.

But this sentence says that the org.gnome.shell schema is not installed

```
let extensionsSchema = new Gio.Settings({ schema: 'org.gnome.shell' });
```

I am calling this line in my own GJS application. And navigating with dconf editor I see this schema and the value there.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tourned out that

```
Gio.Settings.new('org.gnome.shell')
```

actually worked, but when running my code from Gnome Builder, it said that it was not installed because I guess my user is not loaded inside.

Setting this env (USER=myuser) var, allowed me to be able to read the shell schema. It actually makes sense because this schema is user based.